# pyqt images in combobox items

Tags: pyqt, qcombobox

I'm using pyqt and wanted to display different images with each item of a combobox. It doesn't have to be a qcombobox, any form of a drop down menu will do.

Appretiate any answers/ links to examples.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this using `QComboBox`:

```
combo = QComboBox()
combo.addItem(QIcon("path/to/image.png"), "Item 1")
combo.addItem(QIcon("path/to/image2.png"), "Item 2")
...
```